# How to end the alert dialog?

Tags: android

I am making an alert dialog in an application and want to end it when someone clicks on a particular button given in the alert dialog.Even the dismiss() and cancel() are not working for me.

This is the code of the alert dialog:

```
    alertOnButtonDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    TextView alertOnButtonView = new TextView(this);
    alertOnButtonView.setText("The website address of velosys consultancy services is \n velosysconsultancyservices.com.");

    Button alertOnButton = new Button(this);
    alertOnButton.setText("ok");
    alertOnButton.setOnClickListener(alertOnButtonClickListener);
    LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    linearLayout.setLayoutParams( new  LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    linearLayout.setOrientation(1); 
    linearLayout.addView(alertOnButtonView);
    linearLayout.addView(alertOnButton);
    alertOnButtonDialog.setView(linearLayout);
    alertOnButtonDialog.show();
```

And here I want to end it on the clicking of the button:

```
Button.OnClickListener alertOnButtonClickListener = new Button.OnClickListener()
    {  
        @Override  
        public void onClick(View v)
        {   
// code to end the alertDialog
        }
    };
```

Please tell me how to do it?

Comment: write this to dismiss the dialog box : alertOnButtonDialog.dismiss();

Comment: Did you use alertOnButtonDialog.dismiss()?

Comment: The method dismiss() is undefined for the type AlertDialog.Builder   this problem is raised by the compiler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What have you do is, just create a Object of `AlertDialog` using builder.`Create()` method.

then use `dismiss()` method of AlertDialog to dismiss that dialog in button's click.

```
AlertDialog alert;  
alertOnButtonDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
alert = alertOnButtonDialog.create();
```

Now,

```
Button.OnClickListener alertOnButtonClickListener = new Button.OnClickListener()
    {  
        @Override  
        public void onClick(View v)
        {   
         alert.dismiss();
        }
    };
```

Comment: Not solving the problem.This is the error shown by compiler:The method dismiss() is undefined for the type AlertDialog.Builder

Comment: Now `dismiss()` is the method of `AlertDialog` not for `AlertDialog.Builder`. Look at my code carefully..

Comment: Good. Keep it up..! Happy Coding..!

Answer (score 1):

try this..

```
dismissDialog(YourDialog name);
```